# Flink DataSet API: Is GroupBy is not working correctly?

Tags: java, apache-flink

In my Flink Java program I use a GroupBy-Operator as follows:

```
dataSet.groupBy(new KeySelector<myObject, Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer>>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer> groupingKey = new Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer>();

        public Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer> getKey(myObject s) {
            groupingKey.setField(s.getPosition(), 0);
            groupingKey.setField(s.getBand(), 1);
            return groupingKey;
        }
    })
    .reduceGroup(reduceFunction);
```

`getPosition()` returns a `Tuple2<Integer, Integer>` and `getBand()` returns an `int`.

I want to group my dataset on both values. If I have 6 positions and 4 bands I would like to get 24 distinct groups and use the `groupReduce`-function for every group independently. But currently my resulting groups seem to contain various values for the band and the position. I checked this like that in the `groupReduce` function:

```
if (this.band == null) {
    this.band = myObject.getBand();
}
if (this.band != myObject.getBand()) {
    System.out.println("The band should be " + this.band + " but is: " + myObject.getBand());
```

Additionally there are also values in my resulting file which indicate a problem with the grouping. Is it possible that the grouping does not work in my case? Or could this just be a consequence of another potential bug in my code?

Comment: `band` appears to be a member variable of your `GroupReduceFunction`. The `reduce` method of the same `GroupReduceFunction` object may be called several times for different groups (but only once per group). Did you reset `this.band` to null (btw. why null, it should be an `int`, no?) at the end of the `reduce` method? Alternatively, you can make `band` a local variable in `reduce()`.

Comment: @Fabian: Thanks for pointing me in the wright direction. My `this.band` variable was indeed a member variable of the my custom class `GroupReduceFunction` but should have been in the `reduce()` method.

Comment: Did this solve your issue or do you still have problems with the `groupReduce` operator?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment. Everything is working now, I made band a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your check in the `GroupReduceFunction` is not working correctly.
The `GroupReduceFunction.reduce()` can be called several times for different groups. `this.band` is a member variable of your `GroupReduceFunction` and I assume that you do not reset `this.band` at the end of the `reduce()` method.

Hence, `this.band` will `null` only in the first call of `reduce()`. At the beginning of the second call `this.band` will be initialized and won't be set to the band of the current group. Therefore, the following check will fail.